# Загрузка модели из xml

Tags: python, django

Как в Django 1.3 сделать чтобы модель загружалась из xml файла? И если не существует таблицы для этой модели, то она должна создаваться.
Перерыл всю документацию по джанго, ничего не нашел. Желательно использовать готовое решение, а не писать с нуля.

Comment: Нужно динамически создать и класс и таблицу в бд. Класс в принципе может быть уже создан, только поля должны грузиться из xml описания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного не понятно, саму модель или данные модели? Саму модель вы навряд ли можете создать динамически, потому что описание модели - это Python-класс. Точнее, наверное можно, но не логично для SQL и это явно будет костыль.
А данные модели сериализуются и десериализуются просто:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/

Если вам же нужно динамическое создание схем (таблиц) - то это вам в сторону NoSQL - Redis, MongoDB и т.д.

Comment: Будет ли работать стандартный механизм ORM?

Comment: В NoSQL?

Comment: Андрей Басалыга да

Comment: Если хотите использовать ORM с NoSQL, возможно вам стоит посмотреть на django-nonrel (http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel).  
Но я бы не ограничивал себя ORM, а написал бы простой бэкенд для схем сам.

Answer (score 0):

Динамически создать класс = динамически создать модель = динамически написать исходны код модели? Оно того стоит?

Если таблицы нет, но есть модель -> manage.py syncdb причем перед заливкой данных, это понятно.

А чем фикстуры не устраивают?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/

У меня не было такого опыта, по загрузке именно XML файлов, а вот CSV частенько. Причем, пишешь скрипт в сторонке который просто заливает твой CSV в джангу. Обратно уже в JSON, через manage.py dumpdata

Я к тому, что напиши под свой XML парсер и пусть заливает данные.